# Runtime error when using ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename

Tags: excel, vba

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename`: gives

> Runtime error 1004

but hitting Debug>Run> Continue code runs as expected.

I have a macro enable Excel2016 spreadsheet. When updated and saved to PC I also wish to save a copy to my NAS. I have written code (see below) and used identical code, other than filename, for two other spreadsheets. These other two spreadsheets are saved as expected (i.e. to NAS and PC with no Runtime error))
Code as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'Saves the current file to a backup folder and the default folder
'Note that any backup is overwritten
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="\\ReadyNasDuo\Dell\Excelbak\finance18_19.xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I would expect problem file to act like the other two. Anyone any ideas why it does not. Only differences are that problem file is a lot larger, is password protected, has link to another spreadsheet and has far more 'coding'(i.e. more macros and VBA)

Comment: try with your alerts on, I don't think you need to save again in the before save event,

Answer (score 1):

You must also deactivate the events `Application.EnableEvents = False` otherwise your `Save`/`SaveCopyAs` will trigger another `Workbook_BeforeSave` event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'Saves the current file to a backup folder and the default folder
'Note that any backup is overwritten
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="\\ReadyNasDuo\Dell\Excelbak\finance18_19.xlsm"
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save 'needed?

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Also I think you don't need `ActiveWorkbook.Save` because it will save at `End Sub` anyway as long as you don't set `Cancel = True`. The event is called `BeforeSave` not `InsteadOfSave` so the original save action will still happen when `BeforeSave` finished.

Note that `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook` are not the same. I assume that you meant to use `ThisWorkbook` which is the workbook this code is running in, while `ActiveWorkbook` is the one that has the focus (is on top) while the code is running.

Comment: Many thanks for prompt response. Have tried suggestions but still get Runtime 1004 error and clicking Debug>Run>Continue gets code to run OK so I assume that whilst code may not be perfect it does work. As I said the big puzzle is why does the code not work on this file but the exact same code works on two other Excel files?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Put a break point in `Workbook_BeforeSave` and debug your code. Go through it step by step using F8 and see if it runs once or twice or if something odd happens.

Comment: Oddly yesterday code ran OK twice but has since continued to fail since. I have tried your suggestion and each time it 'stalls' at the 'ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs' line. I am coming to conclusion that this may be a network problem. Is that possible and why do other files consistently run OK? I have opened NAS folder with Windows Explorer so I know I am 'connected' before saving file but, again, no joy.  I will try saving file under another name, amend code to do the save copy to another folder on my PC rather than NAS and see what happens to see it is network related.

Comment: Modified code so copy saved to PC rather than NAS - made no difference so not a network problem. Tried running code without the alerts (i.e. with just the 'SaveAs' line.Exact same; Error 1004 but Debug>Run>Continue and code runs OK! Thought it may be a 'Permissions' problem but all three files are identical. There is obviously some sort of 'glitch' in the problem file which I may only resolve by rewriting from scratch - hardly worth the effort due to size and complexity of file plus hitting Debug>Run>Continue is quite quick. It is just frustrating!

Comment: If you assume a faulty file try saving it in the binary format `xlsb`. I explored `xlsm` to be extremely unstable if files are huge for example. Worth a try.

Comment: Have tried your xlsb suggestion but no luck. The file in question is only 2381kb so not really that large. The files that do run ok are 1138kb and 135kb. I will try adding more data to one of these and see if they then fail.

Comment: I have also tried removing password protection and linked files but still have problem. The only other VBA code in the problem files is for sorting data on data entry and so is all completed before I try and save the file so have ruled out possible timing problem with file still sorting as it tries to save. I have also tried adding ChDir to the backup directory before save and then ChDir after save to get back to original directory. This does save file to backup location without Debug problem OK but then does not save file to working directory when I exit!

Comment: Since I cannot reproduce it, it's hard to help here. But that means that it either has to do with your file/data or with the path you save to. Did you try if it also happens on another computer saving to local? So we can at least narrow it down to a  file/data related issue?

Comment: Have tried enlarging files that do run OK and they're still OK. Do'nt think it's a 'path' issue as other two file backups are saved to same path with no problems. It just seems weird that Debug 'stops' at line with path name in it. I have tried copy and paste of line from one of the files that does run ok and still no joy. I will try another computer. This backup save was an afterthought sometime after first using file so If still no joy I will rewrite file from scratch but add backup save VBA from start and gradually build up file to see at what point it fails. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Just had a thought. I will take one of the files that does work and gradually copy and paste worksheets from problem file to see if problem lies in one of worksheets.